# How to restrict download of js files in a website?

Tags: javascript, html

I developed a website using html and javascript. All my logic lies in javascript files. So I want to secure my javascript files being download when the user directly enters the url. Is it possible to restrict?

Comment: you can't restrict any user on download any files from browser moreover you can encrypt it

Comment: You could probably add some check based on the referrer, but at the end of the day it's more likely to cause problems to legitimate visitors than stopping people from seeing the code.  If a browser can download the file for use in the page, so can someone else...

Comment: Classic question, the answer is no. JS is execute at client side, so it much be downloaded before that. Alternatively you can obfuscate your code, but somehow that doesn't really help if someone determines to learn your code.

Answer (score 4):

A javascript file is always downloaded by the client because the client has to be able to execute the code inside. The best thing you can do is [obfuscate the javascript](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/) code.

Comment: This just minifies the file (removes unneccesary spaces, colons etc) and doesnt obfuscate the code.

Comment: It also changes all variable and function names. But I agree, there are better alternatives, it was the first one that came to my mind. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Sadly there isn't a definite way to stop people downloading the JS files, CSS files or image files from your website as these are executed within the browser, the best you can do is to try and minify or obfuscate the files in such a way that they become near impossible to read and therefore use or copy.

A great example of obfuscating would be this: http://javascriptobfuscator.com/

A great example of minifying would be this: http://jscompress.com/

Trying using both for to make sure that there is little to no chance of the code being readable to nosey people.

Answer (score 0):

If you restrict it from being downloaded, it is pretty hard for it to be downloaded by the browser to use it. :)

You can look into packing it:

http://dean.edwards.name/packer/

It will not make it secure, but will make people look the other way if they are too lazy to undo it.

Answer (score 0):

A javascript file is always can downloaded by the client .reason the client has to be able to execute the code insidein web
u can try using  .htaccess like:

```
<Files ~ "(.js|.css)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

[How to restrict/forbid access to specific file types such as .js .css inside a .htaccess file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605078/how-to-restrict-forbid-access-to-specific-file-types-such-as-js-css-inside-a)